# Which episode does Erina Nakiri find out who Soma's dad is?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

I really would like to know because Soma and Erin are mean to each other and I want to see her respecting Soma.

Comment: related question for manga chapter: [When did Erina learn that Yukihira's father was Joichiro?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/25648/2869)

Answer (score 4):

Comparing to the synopsis of the anime episode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Food_Wars!_Shokugeki_no_Soma_episodes#Food_Wars!_Shokugeki_no_Soma:_The_Third_Plate_(San_no_Sara)), Erina found out about Soma's dad on **season 3 episode 12 (episode 49), "The One Who Aims for the Summit"**.

> [...]. Soma then tells Azami that Joichiro is his father, **right as Erina walks in on the conversation, shocking both of them**. [...]
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>